# Idiomatic Clojure way of mimicking Python's yield

Tags: clojure

I'm iterating through a list, building up state as I go, and occasionally when I encounter a certain sentinel, I return a result. If I was doing this in Python, I would lazily `yield` the results, tracking state in the function's local scope as I go:

```
# this is simplified for illustration
def yielder(input_list):
    state = 0
    for item in input_list:
        if item = 'SENTINEL':
            yield state * 2
            state = 0
        else:
            state += item

yielder([1, 5, 2, 5, 'SENTINEL', 4, 6, 7]) # [26, 34]
```

My first implementation uses `reduce`, but that's not as good as `yield` because:

- The value I pass between iterations has both the loop state, and the items's i want to yield, which seems clunky
- It's not lazy

`iterate` could be used to mitigate the latter, but i don't actually want to return something for every input item, so it would require more munging.

**What's an idiomatic way to do this in Clojure?**

Comment: i think a [`lazy-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq) might give me what i want, if i just return `(cons yield-val (yielder ...))` whenever i encounter the sentinel and just `(yielder ...)` otherwise...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build this yourself using lazy-seq as you mention or you could use `partition` and `reduce` to split the problem into phases then thread them together. I'll use the thread-last macro to show each step on it's own:

```lisp
user> (->> [1, 5, 2, 5, :SENTINEL, 4, 6, 7] ;; start with data
           (partition-by #(= :SENTINEL %))  ;; ((1 5 2 5) (:SENTINEL) (4 6 7))
           (take-nth 2)                     ;; ((1 5 2 5) (4 6 7))
           (map #(* 2 (reduce + %))))       ;; the map here keeps it lazy
(26 34)
```

and here it is usin lazy-seq directly:

```lisp
user>  (defn x [items]
         (when (seq items)
           (lazy-seq (cons (* 2 (reduce + (take-while #(not= :SENTINEL %) items)))
                           (x (rest (drop-while #(not= :SENTINEL %) items)))))))
#'user/x
user> (x [1, 5, 2, 5, :SENTINEL, 4, 6, 7])
(26 34)
```

Comment: `for` does not work because the loop terminates when it hits the `:while` condition.

Comment: ohhh I misunderstood, I'll write a different example.

Comment: this answers the question, thanks! tho it is slightly semantically different, since the original algorithm sums items and multiplies by two.

Comment: `#(= :SENTINEL %)` is better written as `#{:SENTINEL}`

Answer (score 3):

[The Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) has a way to do this using `lazy-gen`/`yield` which mimics a Python generator function:

```
(ns xyz
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))

(def data-1 [1 5 2 5 :SENTINEL 4 6 7] )
(def data-2 [1 5 2 5 :SENTINEL 4 6 7 :SENTINEL] )

(defn yielder [vals]
  (t/lazy-gen
    (let [state (atom 0)]
      (doseq [item vals]
        (if (= :SENTINEL item)
          (do
            (t/yield (* 2 @state))
            (reset! state 0))
          (swap! state + item))))))

(yielder data-1) => (26)
(yielder data-2) => (26 34)
```

Note that the original problem description had a bug, since the cumulative state is only output when the `:SENTENEL` tag is encountered. The different outputs for `data-1` and `data-2` illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Though I prefer Arthur's first solution, this can also be written in a lower level style, not using lazy-seq:

```
(defn f [xs]
  (loop [[x & xs :as xxs] xs, n 0, ret []]
    (cond (empty? xxs) (conj ret (* n 2))
          (= x :sentinel) (recur xs 0 (conj ret (* n 2)))
          :else (recur xs (+ n x) ret))))
```

Comment: The point of lazy-seq is to be lazy, which you've lost here. Try Arthur's version and yours on `(interpose :SENTINEL (range))`, using `take` to get only the first few elements.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought of only non-lazy inputs. Then, I'll +1 Arthur's.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my version using `reduce`:

```
(def v [1 5 2 5 "SENTINEL" 4 6 7])

(defn r []
  (let [{:keys [result current]}
        (reduce (fn [acc x]
                  (case x
                    "SENTINEL" (-> acc
                                   (update-in [:result] conj (* 2 (:current acc)))
                                   (update-in [:current] (constantly 0)))
                    (update-in acc [:current] #(+ x %))))
                {:result [] :current 0} v)]
    (conj result (* 2 current))))

user> (r)
[26 34]
```