# Generating integer partitions - Converting python code with yield to clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to generate integer partitions for a number and stumbled upon [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/218332/) which seemed quite brief and elegant:

```
def partitions(n):
    # base case of recursion: zero is the sum of the empty list
    if n == 0:
        yield []
        return

    # modify partitions of n-1 to form partitions of n
    for p in partitions(n-1):
        yield [1] + p
        if p and (len(p) < 2 or p[1] > p[0]):
            yield [p[0] + 1] + p[1:]
```

So, I attempted at converting this to Clojure and failed miserably:

```
(defn- partitions [n]
  (if (zero? n) []
      (for [p (partitions (dec n))]
        (let [res [(concat [1] p)]]
          (if (and (not (empty? p))
                   (or (< (count p) 2) (> (second p) (first p))))
            (conj res (into [(inc (first p))] (subvec p 1)))
            res)))))
```

^^ Above is wrong. For example:

```
eul=> (partitions 4)
()
```

Should I be thinking of lazy sequences?

I have trouble reasoning about the python code and my attempts at converting it so far have failed. Any help for me to figure out how to do this is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436677/idiomatic-clojure-way-of-mimicking-pythons-yield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tupelo library has an implementation of Python's `yield` function.  Here is a translation:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core )

(defn partitions [n]
  (lazy-gen
    (if (zero? n)
      (yield [])
      (doseq [p (partitions (dec n))]
        (yield (glue [1] p))
        (when (and (not-empty? p)
                (or (< (count p) 2)
                  (< (first p) (second p))))
          (yield (prepend (inc (first p))
                   (rest p))))))))

(partitions 4) => 
    ([1 1 1 1] [1 1 2] [2 2] [1 3] [4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the active end of a partition is at the front, it had better be a list than a vector. This simplifies the finger ends of your code.

Otherwise sticking to your structure, we get, in Clojure, something like ...

```
(defn partitions [n]
  (if (zero? n)
    '(())
    (apply concat
      (for [p (partitions (dec n))]
        (let [res [(cons 1 p)]]
          (if (and (not (empty? p))
                   (or (< (count p) 2) (> (second p) (first p))))
            (conj res (cons (inc (first p)) (rest p)))
            res))))))
```

It works:

```
=> (partitions 4)
((1 1 1 1) (1 1 2) (2 2) (1 3) (4))
```

---

Where did you go wrong? You failed to disentangle the `yield`s properly.

- The `for` returns a sequence of vectors of one or two partitions. You
  have to concatenate them into a single sequence.
- And your base case should return a sequence of partitions  too - not
  a single empty partition as you try to do. The algorithm takes it as
  an empty sequence, which propagates itself up the recursion chain.
  Hence your result.

There are some minor improvements to be made, but I discarded them in favour of sticking nearer to your code.